# Trespassing on Public Parks

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, politics-government, real-estate, dina-dmalchusa-dina

If a state or federal park is closed, is it against halacha to go there anyway (if you are not damaging the property)?

(Thoughts: I would assume it is [g'neiva](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.376?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) because it is not my property. 
However, which entity owns the park - the government or the people? Does the fact that I pay taxes give me a right to use the property at my discretion as long as I am careful to avoid damaging it or are there American laws against this? Assuming it is not g'neiva, is the law binding if many people don't keep it, and/or it is not enforced, and it doesn't hurt anybody?)

Comment: "nobody keeps it" Is that the case here?

Comment: I assume that if it's closed, there are American laws against going there (by definition).

Comment: Re you last point, see [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38386/does-dina-demalchusa-dina-apply-to-laws-no-one-keeps).