# Shalosh Shevuoth (The Three Oaths) - halacha or aggadata

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, eretz-yisrael, nedarim-shevuot, maseches-kesubos

I am aware that there is a long standing argument about whether the Shalosh Shevuot<sup>(1)</sup> are a Halachic concept to be reckoned with or "just" an aggadata. I'm sure that there are many varied opinions in Jewish tradition. I would like to know if there is any final concensus on this question. I am not asking about its applicability to Zionism or Medinat Yisroel but just about the concept of the Shevuoth itself.

---

<sup>(1)</sup><sub>Masechet Ketubot 111a: And Rabbi Zera? - That text is required for [an exposition] like that of Rabbi Jose son of Rabbi Hanina who said: 'What was the purpose of those three adjurations? - One, that Israel shall not go up [all together as if surrounded] by a wall {Rashi: together, by force}; the second, that whereby the Holy One, blessed be He, adjured Israel that they shall not rebel against the nations of the world; and the third is that whereby the Holy One, blessed be He, adjured the idolaters that they shall not oppress Israel too much'.</sub>

Comment: `I would like to know if there is any final concensus [sic] on this question` In the absence of the Sanhedrin HaGadol, I am not sure what sort of "final consensus "  can be reached. In this particular case, I assume you are aware that followers of Satmar, for example, definitely disagree with the view demonstrated by R. Melamed cited [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53507/8775). So there is definitely not consensus.

Comment: `I am aware that there is a long standing argument about whether the Shalosh Shevuot are a Halachic concept to be reckoned with` Could you cite any opinion that hold that it is a halakhic concept? R. Melamed's citations of the  Avnei Neizer, Rif, Rosh, Rishonim, Rambam, Shulhan Arukh, and P'ney Yehoshua, to prove the opposite, seem pretty impressive.

Comment: see [this](http://www.kby.org/hebrew/torat-yavneh/view.asp?id=3970)  link

Comment: Rambam, Rav Shlomo Ben Yehuda, Rabbi Elazar Ha'Kalir, Rashi, Ba'alei Tosfos, The Rokeach, Rabbi Yeshaya di'Trani, Ishtori Haparchi, Rabbi Yehuda Chalavah, Rabbeinu Bichaya, The Rivash, The Rashbash.

Comment: Achronim: Maharshadam,Kli Yakar, Shelah, Abarbanel, Megilas Esther (Leon), Rav C.E. Shapiro, Rav Isaac Karmana,  Be'er  Hagolah, Rav Chaim ben Bitzalel, Rav Yosef Chaim Sonnenfeld,  Rav Elazar Azikri, Rav Yakov Sasportas, Ohr Ha'Chaim, Ramchal, Rav Yakov Emden, Mirkeves Hamishna, Chida, Yisroel Shklov, Rav T.H. Lehren, Rav Y.S. Natanson, the Steipler  (Kanievsky), Rav Chaim Kanievsky,  Rav Hershel Shechter, Rav H. Lichtenstein  (Kolomaya) Rav S.R. Hirsch, Rav Y.Y.L. Perlman  (the Minske Gadol), the Aruch Hashulchan, Ben Ish Chai, Bnei Yisoschor, Chozeh Milublin. [PARTIAL LIST]

Comment: What is this list? I found only Rav Eshtori Haparchi in the book Kaftor VaPerach who said   ומיהו לא יעלו על מנת לכבוש עד שיבא הקץ and I guess that some people can say that the Kets begins precisely, התחלתא דגאולה. Obviously in Mi yodeya the Machloket about sionism will not be resolved. But nowaday, there is no Kibush. There are already Jewish People in Israel, to defend them is a great Mitsva. A part of the rabbanim in the above list live in Israel. To go in West Bank is no Kibush. it is already nichbash.

Comment: I clarified in the question that I am not trying to relate this question to Zionism at all. I just want to know if the Shalosh Shevuot are a Halachic concept that has to be reckoned with or is it Agaddata that would not play a role in decision to conquer Eretz Yisroel. If it is a Halacha then we would be able to move on to the next question about why it is not applicable to our situation. Or why it is.